# Background tasks on app engine using Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, parsing

I'm programming novice.  I'm looking for a source that will clearly explain how to run background tasks on App Engine (Java).

I currently have an App up and running but would like to have a background task that parses another site and creates tables that will be consumed by my App.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official site is really good: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/

Comment: Are there any full blown examples?

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to do this.

1) Add a new task to the App Engine task queue. Requests running as "push" tasks can run for up to 10 minutes. (The run just like regular http requests.)

2) Allocate a "backend" instance, this is basically an instance of your application that is allowed to run forever. (The can accept http requests but you need to target them specifically.)

3) In the context of a request you can launch a thread (using App Engine's thread API). There are two types of threads. a) Request and b) Background.  Background threads can only be started in a "backend" instance and "request" threads are interrupted when the current request completes.

App Engine task queues are probably the easiest way to do what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is 2 years old, but I think Google app engine modules are architecturally more suited to your problem.

Docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/

Having said that, task queues and backends (background threads) can solve the problem too.